# A question in an oriented connected graph.

Tags: graph-theory

In an oriented connected graph, I knew E-V+1 is called the number of circuits. I have a feeling that it may be related to the number of "independent" loop(a path from a vertex to itself). But could it be shown concretely?

Comment: I've been doing graph theory for a long time, and haven't ever seen $e-v+1$ referred to in this manner.  Usually, I hear it called the _excess_ of a graph -- the number of edges beyond the $v-1$ required to form a tree.  Even that, however, is always in an undirected context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In topology, one studies the "1st cycle group" of a graph $G$, denoted $C_1(G)$. Although referred to as a group, one can think of it as a vector space. The number $1+E-V$ is the dimension of this vector space.

It is not quite accurate, as the answer of @farhbach shows, to call $E-V+1$ the "number of circuits". It would be better to call it the "maximum number of linearly independent cycles". In the example of @fahrbach, any two of the three cycles that he mentions are linearly independent, but the three of them together are not linearly independent.

One can define $C_1(G)$ rigorously with linear algebra, but I'll give an intuitive explanation, using the answer of @fahrbach as an example. First, choose orientations of the edges of $G$. For the example, there are five edges $AB$, $AC$, $AD$, $BD$, $CD$ where for example $AB$ is oriented to have initial vertex $A$ and terminal vertex $B$. A "chain" on the graph $G$ is an assignment of real numbers to the edges. One might think of a chain as measuring some kind of "rate of flow" of some physical substance. A chain is a "cycle" if at each vertex the total inflow equals the total outflow. Cycles form a vector space, which in topology is denoted $C_1(G)$.

For instance,
$$AB+BD-AD = 1 \cdot AB + 1 \cdot BD - 1 \cdot DA
$$
is a cycle, because at the vertex $A$ the edge $+AB$ contributes an outflow of $1$ which is balanced by the inflow of $1$ created by the edge $-AD$. Similarly at $B$ and $D$ which have a balanced inflow of $1$ and outflow of $1$. At $C$ the inflow and outflow are both zero. So the total inflow and outflow at each vertex of zero, which makes $AB+BD-AD$ a cycle.

Cycles can have any real coefficients, so for example 
$$AB + BD - 2AD + AC + CD = (AB+BD-AD) + (AC+CD-AD)
$$
is also a cycle.

So the answer to your question is that $E+V-1$ is the rank of $C_1(G)$, meaning the size of a "basis" meaning a maximal, linearly independent set of cycles. In the example, $AB+BD-AD$ and $AC+CD-AD$ form a basis of size $E+V-1=2$.

Comment: In fact, I found it as an exercise in a book about homological algebra. When it is a linear vector space, I could give a proof about it. But if it is over a ring, is the rank of $C_1(G)$ still E-V+1? It means we take the edges as a basis of a free R-module. Is there any reference to "maximum number of linearly independent cycles"? If it is true, I think the rank of $C_1(G)$ is still E-V+1.

Comment: This is still true, yes, because what one can show in general is that if you define $C_1(G)$ with coefficients in a ring $R$, denoted $C_1(G;R)$, then $C_1(G;R)$ is a free module over $R$, meaning simply a direct sum of copies of $R$.

Comment: In fact you can be quite explicit about generators of $C_1(G;R)$. Pick a maximal tree $T$ in $G$, let $E_1,…,E_K$ be the edges of $G-T$ each with a fixed orientation, for each $E_k$ let $\gamma_k$ be the path in $T$ from the terminal endpoint of $E_k$ to the initial endpoint of $E_k$. Then the cycles $E_1 + \gamma_1$, …, $E_K + \gamma_K$ are a basis for $C_1(G;R)$. I am assuming $R$ has an identity $1$ so $E_1 + \gamma_1$ really means $1 \cdot E_1 + 1 \cdot$(all the edges along $\gamma_1$).

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be the case. Consider the following graph $G$:

```
A - - - B
| \     |
|   \   |
|     \ |
C - - - D
```

There are $5$ edges and $4$ vertices, so the number of circuits is $E-V+1=5-4+1=2$. Note though that there are $3$ circuits containing A: ABDA, ACDA, and ABDCA. It must be counting something else or nothing at all.

Comment: So if I take ABDCA as an "addition" of ABDA and ACDA. In this meaning, ABDA and ACDA are "independent". So the number is 2. Do you have some reference to "the number of circuits"?